# python-oauth2 with Twitter's oauth_callback

Tags: python, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth, twython

I'm using [Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) as my Twitter API wrapper, and oauth2 to handle authentication.  I'm trying to have a use login via twitter, and then redirecting him after the oauth dance to a dynamically generated oauth_callback.  This, however, appears to be impossible to do with these libraries straight out of the box.  My problem is that my oauth client (python-oauth2), doesnt support callback urls.  I find this very strange because this is the default oauth client used by Twython -- why would they bother writing code to accomodate the use of a dynamic callback and then bundle the library with an oauth client that doesn't support callbacks?  [Line 54 is set to false](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/twython.py#L54), therefore my callback url is never included in the request token url, as [required in the oAuth 1.0a specs](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#request-token).

I've tried modifying both Twython and oauth2, but I keep running into problems.  I'd like to know if there is an alternative to python-oauth2 that supports oauth_callback, or maybe an alternative twitter library that would handle the oauth properly.

Comment: Hey there! I'm the author of Twython - this is a good issue to fix; as I noted in another comment on this thread, I'll patch it up later and release it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to be of use.  Thanks for the great work on Twython!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://milindshakya.tumblr.com/post/4208580364/overriding-twitters-default-callback-url-using-oauth)

All you have to do is pass Twython the parameter callback_url and replace line 205 in Twython.py with

`resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "POST",body=urllib.urlencode({'oauth_callback':my_callback_url}))`

Notice, if you want twitter to respect your oauth_callback argument, the request must be a POST.

Comment: Hey there! I'm the author of Twython - this is a nice find, I'll add a patch in later this week to fix it right up! ;)